# Importing modules on portable python

Tags: python, module, portable-python

I am running PortablePython_1.1_py2.6.1 on a USB stick. My code relies on some modules that are not preinstalled. Does anyone know whether it is possible to add new modules to a portable python installation? Simply copying in folders into site-lib does not seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What does `import sys; print sys.path` say?  It should be the list of directories and zipfiles where Python (portable or otherwise) looks for modules to import.  Just copy your modules into one of those directories or zipfiles, or `sys.path.append('/whatever/dir')` if you have your modules in `/whatever/dir` and want to keep them there (the latter approach will last only for the current session, be it interactive or a script's execution).

Comment: This deos not work for me : >>> import sys; print sys.path
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.path
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: And so, once I know these path names, how to install a module please ?

Comment: I download the zip archive of a module, I put it in one of those directories, and that does not work. What do I have to do in addition ?

Answer (score 6):

[This closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160766/install-packages-with-portable-python#comment16298000_12160766) was actually asked for Portable Python 3.2. I have found a nice way to install modules with Windows :

- download the zip archive of [the distribute module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/#installing-and-using-distribute)
- install it by typing

  MyPythonPath\App\python MyDownloadPath\setup.py install

in a DOS commander

- Now Easy Install is installed in folder MyPythonPath\App\Scripts. So type e.g.

  MyPythonPath\App\Scripts\easy_install-3.2 numpy

to install the numpy module.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and maybe this is a possibility that was not possible at this time but simply:

- From a command prompt go to your Portable Python's python.exe folder with `cd <path to Portable Python>\App\Python`,
- Run (for instance to install `selenium` module): `.\python.exe -m pip install selenium`,
- Now you have `selenium` module installed, you can check in your `<path to Portable Python>\App\Python\Lib\site-packages` that you have now `selenium` and its dependencies.