# install packages with Portable Python

Tags: python, portable-python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing modules on portable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746542/importing-modules-on-portable-python)

I am a new Python user. I have installed Portable Python on the PC I use at work (the OS is Windows XP and I don't have administrator privileges) and I don't knwo how to install packages. Except for the Pyper package the installation: put the files in the Python directory and type "python setup.py" in a DOS console. But I would like to install numpy and pandas. The zip archive contain several folders and I don't know what to do. The Windows installer (exe file) does not work because Python is not in the windows registry and it is not possible to type the path with the installation process.

Comment: have you tried easy_install? BTW, I'm not sure if it works or not.

Comment: Hello. I don't know what is easy_install.

Comment: Laurent http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746542/importing-modules-on-portable-python contains the answer that you are looking for. I also flagged the question as an exact duplicate.

Comment: The answer is not really helpful for me ! (I have added some comments)

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı there's no setuptools installer for Python 3.2 !

Comment: I haven't jumped to python3.x yet, so you are on your own. Sadly.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı I have found a solution for Python 3.2, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746542/importing-modules-on-portable-python/12191949#12191949