# Use Selenium with Python Portable

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, portable-applications

My question seems somewhat inane, but I cannot seem to find any resources for what I need to do.

Essentially I'm using my work computer to write python applications in my spare time. I'm using Python Portable (syntax version 3.2) because I do not have administrative access and can't do things with path variables etc.

How (if possible) do I install or import selenium so I can use it in Python Portable?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on answer found [Importing modules on portable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746542/importing-modules-on-portable-python)
and [How to install external libraries with Portable Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171658/how-to-install-external-libraries-with-portable-python)

Check for what `import sys; print sys.path` says?

It displays the list of directories and zipfiles where portable python looks for modules to import. Just copy your modules into one of those directories or zipfiles, or sys.path.append('/whatever/dir') if you have your modules in /whatever/dir and want to keep them there (the latter approach will last only for the current session, be it interactive or a script's execution).

---

---

Also on their [FAQs](http://portablepython.com/wiki/FAQ/)

*You don’t have package I need, can I add it?*

For simpler packages you can use easy install or even extract them in site-packages folder of
the Portable Python distribution. However some packages are installing additional dependencies
in windows system folders - in this case your Portable Python distribution will not work once 
you move it to some other workstation. Make sure to do proper testing !

---

Comment: You just made this ridiculously simple. I don't know why those other answers didn't come up in my searches, but you rock. Thank you!